# does Jacoco require a test source class to create coverage reports?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am new to this so what I would like to ask is does Jacoco require test sources to generate its coverage reports since from what I've read you only need to set it up inside the pom.xml file for it to work and that the only JUnit requires test sources or I am wrong in my assumption?

I am following this link http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074515/core-java/unit-test-code-coverage-with-maven-and-jacoco.html